# TeXnicCenter - spelling not working correctly

Tags: grammar, spelling, texnic-center

I have installed 2.02 Stable 64 bit version of TeXnicCenter and have following problem with spelling check. In one of my existing LaTeX document the grammar of the text in English is checked correctly and all typos are being underlined. In this file German language is not being recognise although I change setting for the language in the options for spelling. However, in other of my existing LaTex document the spelling tool is not recognising English text but it recognises text in German.

Here some hint: It could be that the other LaTex file has been created within German Windows environment. Now I have the Win 7 environment in English. Is it possible that it is connected with the text formatting? Is it possible to change it? Or is there a different cause?

Some other hint: When I generate a new LaTex file the spelling works fine for both English and German. So it is just the problem with the existing document.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the German text contains UTF-8 accented characters, and the spell checker is looking for Latin-1, or vice-versa? Maybe try "planting" a misspelled German word written only in ASCII characters (no accented characters)?

Answer (score 3):

Good hint from your side towards text encoding Phil. Solution is a bit different though. Apparently TexnicCenter is saving .tex files with ANSI encoding as default. As soon as .tex files are saved with UTF-8 encoding, spelling check works fine. There are not options to be set in the program. One has to go through Files->Save As and set the encoding while saving.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic but here is what solved my issue: manually change the project language. Go to project > properties and then change the language there.